# How to persist bash variables from one code chunck to another in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown

I have the following `rmarkdown` example, where I want to persist the `shell` variables from one code chunk to another. It seems it runs a new shell for each chuck. Is it possible to get a single shell session for the whole document?

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    highlight: zenburn
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
---

text

```{bash, engine.opts='-l'}
TEST="12345"
echo $TEST
```

more text

```{bash, engine.opts='-l'}
echo $TEST
```
````

Compiling with

```
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd', 'html_document')
```

and the result is displayed below

[image]

Comment: I have tried to figure this out myself, and AFAICT this is not an implemented feature.